# Instagram followers are not showing?

Tags: php, laravel-5, instagram-api

I'm using this code to get followers count!

```
<?php
    $api_key = '------';
    $user_id = '------';
    $data = @file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$user_id/?client_id=$api_key");
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    echo '<pre/>';
    print_r($data);
    echo $data['data']['counts']['followed_by'];
    ?>
```

Comment: Is there any output ? What happens when you remove the @ before file_get_contents ?

Comment: Show your output

Comment: remove your api key and user id.. otherwise you will be posting spam within a couple minutes.

Comment: It is showing blank box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing because you can't use a client ID to access that function of the API.

You need to get an `Access Token` by sending a user to the authorisation url. Read about it in the [Instagram Docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

After that, you make the request to `/users` using the `Access Token` from before.